# how to select element in multi select box in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Currently working on **Selenium WebDriver** and using **Java**.. I want to know to select values in **Multi-select** box. The options are already selected.. If i want to select any two or more option. how can perform the action.

The HTML is follows:

```
<select id="swpacksId" multiple="" style="width: 125px; display: none;" name="swPacks[]">
<option selected="" value="ADVIP">ADVIP</option>
<option selected="" value="ADVLEG">ADVLEG</option>
<option selected="" value="ADVSEC">ADVSEC</option>
<option selected="" value="Boot">Boot</option>
<option selected="" value="H323">H323</option>
<option selected="" value="IBC">IBC</option>
<option selected="" value="MULTI">MULTI</option>
<option selected="" value="None">None</option>
</select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a function pass a list of values use any delimiter lets say comma as a delimiter:

```
public static void selectMultipelValues(String multipleVals) {
   String multipleSel[] = multipleVals.split(",");

   for (String valueToBeSelected : multipleSel) {
      new Select(driver.findElement(By.id(propId))).selectByVisibleText(valueToBeSelected);
      driver.findElement(By.id(ddObj)).sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL);
   }
}
```

Comment: What is `ddObj`? How can this work: First you select something, then you send `CONTROL`, then you select the next item?

Comment: Be careful regarding taking a string and then splitting on comma (,). What if the visible text itself of one or more options have commas in them? Why not instead have `selectMultipleValues` take a string array directly?

Answer (score 3):

If you have `Utils` static method like this:

```
public static void selectTheDropDownList(WebElement dropDown,String text)
{
    Select select = new Select(dropDown);
    select.selectByVisibleText(text);       
}
```

and you can do like this, to select multiple options:

```
Utils.selectTheDropDownList(dropDown,text1);
Utils.selectTheDropDownList(dropDown,text2);
. . . 
Utils.selectTheDropDownList(dropDown,textn);
```

This should work.

Comment: What/Where is `Utils`? Does it belong to Selenium or Java?

Comment: Look once more, `Utils` is the example class name that contains the `selectTheDropDownList` method described just here

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
final String[] textOptions = {"value1", "value2"};
final WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("someId"));
final Select dropdown = new Select(element);
final List<WebElement> options = dropdown.getOptions();
final Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
final boolean isMultiple = dropdown.isMultiple();
if (isMultiple) {
    dropdown.deselectAll();
}
builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);
for (String textOption : textOptions) {
    for (WebElement option : options) {
        final String optionText = option.getText().trim();
        if (optionText.equalsIgnoreCase(textOption)) {
            if (isMultiple) {
                if (!option.isSelected()) {
                    builder.click(option);
                }
            } else {
                option.click();
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
builder.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check if below url helps you

http://selenium.polteq.com/en/controlling-a-selectbox-or-dropdownbox-with-selenium-webdriver/

You can check below option

```
public void selectByValue() { 
     Select selectBox = 
           new Select(driver.findElement(By .cssSelector("select#id_contact")));       
     selectBox.selectByValue("2"); 
}

public void selectByIndex() {  
     Select selectBox = 
           new Select(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("select#id_contact"))); 
     selectBox.selectByIndex(2); 
}
```

you can change it according to your requirement

Answer (score 1):

You need to click element with control.
Here is documentation how to make such action
https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions

In our case it could be:

```
Select select = new Select(element);

Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
.click(select.getOptions().get(2))
.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);

builder.build().perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code, its simple and easy!! It worked for me.

```
Select dd1 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("swPacks[]")));
dd1.selectByVisibleText("ADVIP");
dd1.selectByVisibleText("ADVLEG");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have spent quite some time trying to simulate a click with the control key pressed with the webdriver for Chrome. After some investigation it appeared, that when you generate a click on an OPTION element of a multiselect, no click actually happens. Instead, a change event is genetared in the browser. This leads to the situation, where subsequent "clicks" on other options of the multiselect do not clear the previously selected options, which is sometimes unwanted behavior.
To solve this I have come up with the following solution:

```
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
if(controlNeeded)
    actions.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL);
actions.moveToElement((WebElement) option_you_want_to_click);
actions.clickAndHold();
actions.pause(100);
actions.release();
if(controlNeeded)
    actions.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);
actions.build().perform();
```

This way you can select both single and multiple elements depending on the Ctrl key.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Select(driver.findElementByXPath("XXXXXXXXXXX"))).selectByIndex(2);
```

Comment: The above can be used if you have a drop down/combo box.Index starts from 0.

Comment: This is not answering the question. He asked about multi selection and your answer only works for a single selection.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple section you can do:

```
Select select = new Select(element);
Actions builder = new Actions(driver);
builder.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL)
.click(select.getOptions().get(2))
.click(select.getOptions().get(3))
.click(select.getOptions().get(4))
.keyUp(Keys.CONTROL);

builder.build().perform();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code below-->  //https://jqueryui.com/selectable/

```
int i=0;<br>
Actions actObj = new Actions(driverObj);    <br>    
for(WebElement ele: selectableList){<br>
    actObj.moveToElement(ele);<br>
    actObj.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).click(ele).build().perform();<br>
    System.out.println("selectableList["+i+"] = "+ele.getText()+" Clicked");<br>
    i++;<br>
}<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
WebElement programs = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\'contentblock\']/section/div[6]/select"));

programs.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL+"a");
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding extra information such as what your code does and how it helps the OP.

Answer (score -2):

I have written code like this.. 1st i deselected all the values in the multi select box then i selected the values which i want.. It is working properly..

```
Log.info("Clicking on Softwarepack dropdown");
JavascriptExecutor executor31 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor31.executeScript("document.getElementById('swpacksId').style.display='block';");
Select select31 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("swpacksId")));
select31.deselectAll();
select31.selectByVisibleText("ADVLEG");
Thread.sleep(6000);
JavascriptExecutor executor32 = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor32.executeScript("document.getElementById('swpacksId').style.display='block';");
Select select32 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("swpacksId")));
select32.selectByVisibleText("SIP");
```