# Selecting multiple values in Listbox

Tags: java, html, selenium

How to select multiple values in listbox.  I have tried with the below code, it selects the value only once. Please suggest and provide an alternative way to select the multiple values at the time

```
WebElement Groupid_selection =driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
Select Group = new Select (Groupid_selection);
Group.selectByVisibleText("aa");
Group.selectByVisibleText("bb");
Group.selectByVisibleText("cc");
```

Below is the HTML:

```
<div id="Dimension" style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:585px;width:120px;height:40px;">
  <select class="bf" style="width: 100%;height:48px;" name="Dimension" id="Dimension1"
            onchange="CheckDimentionChangeAndUpdate(this);" size="3" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1" selected="selected" title=aa>aa</option>
    <option value="9" title="bb">bb</option>
    <option value="4" title="cc">cc</option>
    <option value="7" title="dd">dd</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add some relevant HTML?

Comment: <div id="Dimension" style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:585px;width:120px;height:40px;"><select class="bf" style="width: 100%;height:48px;" name="Dimension" id="Dimension1" onchange="CheckDimentionChangeAndUpdate(this);" size="3" multiple="multiple"><option value="1" selected="selected" title=aa>aa</option><option value="9" title="bb">bb/option><option value="4" title="cc">cc</option><option value="7" title="dd">dd</option></select></div>

Comment: Please find the html section for the above code

Comment: guys any updates on the above condition. i am still struggling on the section. Please guide and provide alternative solutions

Comment: did you have a look to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421790/how-to-select-element-in-multi-select-box-in-selenium-webdriver ?

Comment: I have tried with the attached samples , but not in use. it is selected single values only while execution...

Comment: any solutions for this ?????

Comment: Hey try 'Actions' class and use keyboard event (Ctrl-down) until you select all the options.

Comment: Fix up indentation of HTML

Comment: could you please elaborate  your comments..

Comment: Guys, This multiple selection is working for me when using IE WebDriver, but when i use the Chrome WebDriver , it is not at all selecting multiple values . Could you please help on that

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your given HTML (reformatted), the id of the *select* element is `Dimension1`:

```
<div id="Dimension" style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:585px;width:120px;height:40px;">
  <select class="bf" style="width: 100%;height:48px;" name="Dimension" id="Dimension1" onchange="CheckDimentionChangeAndUpdate(this);" size="3" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1" selected="selected" title=aa>aa</option>
    <option value="9" title="bb">bb</option>
    <option value="4" title="cc">cc</option>
    <option value="7" title="dd">dd</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I created a *test.html* and used the following code (Selenium and Firefox Driver Version 2.45.0):

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Selenium2Example {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    driver.get("http://localhost:8080/test.html");
    WebElement Groupid_selection = driver.findElement(By.id("Dimension1"));
    Select Group = new Select(Groupid_selection);
    Group.selectByVisibleText("aa");
    Group.selectByVisibleText("bb");
    Group.selectByVisibleText("cc");

    List<WebElement> options = Group.getAllSelectedOptions();
    options.forEach(e -> System.out.println("Selected element: " +
       e.getText() + "[value=" +
       e.getAttribute("value") +  ", title=" +
       e.getAttribute("title") +  "]"));

    driver.quit();
  }
}
```

and all three elements (aa,bb,cc) will be selected. Output:

```
Selected element: aa[value=1, title=aa]
Selected element: bb[value=9, title=bb]
Selected element: cc[value=4, title=cc]
```

Comment: it is not at all selected all the values . it is selecting single value only.

Comment: What is your environment, your driver etc. - as written, with the version above and FirefoxDriver the selection works fine. Can your provide the concrete code that is not working since the snippet in your post is not working on the HTML you provided.

Comment: i have been using chromedriver_win32(2) driver and Eclipse Standard/SDK - Version: Luna Service Release 1 (4.4.1).

Comment: WebElement Dimension_selection = driver.findElement(By.id("Dimension1"));
             Select SelectDimension = new Select (Dimension_selection);
             SelectDimension.deselectAll();
             SelectDimension.selectByVisibleText("aa");
             SelectDimension.selectByVisibleText("bb");

Comment: List <WebElement> Selections = SelectDimension.getAllSelectedOptions();
            int noofitemsselected =  Selections.size();
             System.out.println("noofitemsselected" + noofitemsselected);
             for (int i=0; i<=noofitemsselected-1; i++)
             {
              System.out.println("ItemsSelections" + Selections.get(i).getText());
              System.out.println("Itemsvalue" + Selections.get(i).getAttribute("value"));
              System.out.println("Itemstitle" + Selections.get(i).getAttribute("title"));
             }