# multiple values selection is happening in IE WebDriver not in Chrome driver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have tried to select the multiple values in optional box , i have used the below code to select the values , the selection is happening on IE WebDriver But while using the same code on Chrome WebDriver , the multiple selection is not happing . COuld you please help on that. I have used the below chrome driver chromedriver_win32(2).

```
  WebElement Groupid_selection =driver.findElement(By.id("id"));
   Select Group = new Select (Groupid_selection);
      Group.selectByVisibleText("aa");
      Group.selectByVisibleText("bb");
     Group.selectByVisibleText("cc"); 


     <div id="Dimension" style="position:absolute;top:5px;left:585px;width:120px;height:40px;">
  <select class="bf" style="width: 100%;height:48px;" name="Dimension" id="Dimension1"
        onchange="CheckDimentionChangeAndUpdate(this);" size="3" multiple="multiple">
<option value="1" selected="selected" title=aa>aa</option>
<option value="9" title="bb">bb</option>
<option value="4" title="cc">cc</option>
<option value="7" title="dd">dd</option>
 </select>
 </div>
```

Comment: Any comments please...

Comment: Have you tried this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421790/how-to-select-element-in-multi-select-box-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: Already i have tried those options. but in chrome browser multiple selection is not working. It is working in IE browser. Could you please provide any other way to handle this situation

Comment: You will have to pass Ctrl+click or Ctrl+Space to the options to be selected.

Comment: Guys could you please confirm this is the chrome driver issue or my code level issue..