# How to select multiple select options with selenium

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

I am writing a test using Selenium Webdriver. I want to select the second option of every dropdown menu that may appear on the page. The number of dropdown menus will be different every time.

This is what I've come up with and It does not work:

```
if (driver.findElements({tagName: 'select'})) {
  var select = driver.findElements({tagName: 'select'});
  for (i = 0; i < select.length; i ++) {
        i++;
        driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath('//select['+i+']/option[2]')).click();
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<select class="form-control" name="answer_4282670">
    <option value="0">Please choose one...</option>
    <option value="option a">option a</option>
    <option value="option b">option b</option>
    <option value="option c">option c</option>
    <option value="Other" data-other-flag="">Other</option>
</select>
```

The value of each option will be different in each instance, so we can not choose anything by its value

How can I fix this so it will click the second option of a menu for each one that will show up (if one shows up)?

Comment: The HTML to select would be nice

Comment: see updated question

Answer (score 0):

I am using webdriver js, and nth child works for me:

```
driver.click('#my_select_box').click('#my_select_box option:nth-child(3)')
```

Comment: Thank you. any insight on the looping logic? I would like this to repeat as many times as there are select elements

Comment: Will the class always be form-control or can the selects vary in that regard?

Comment: the class will always be form-control, however the class for all elements on the page is form-control

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is not a direct anwser, but i cant comment your post yet so i hope you are fine with that.

I havent worked with selenium myself, but i wanted to start using it, and I tried to learn alot from this website: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/AdvancedUserInteractions and after doing some research i found a similar question. [how to select element in multi select box in selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21421790/how-to-select-element-in-multi-select-box-in-selenium-webdriver) The big difference is, that the anwser was given in java.

Even though its not the perfect solution I hope those 2 links can help you, and again sorry that I cant write that as a comment

Answer (score 0):

You can apply this logic: define a list variable with accessing second option of all dropdown like `.form-control > option:nth-child(3)` then iterete over this and call `.click` event for each item.

```
if (driver.findElements({css: '.form-control > option:nth-child(3)'})) {
  var selects = driver.findElements({css: '.form-control > option:nth-child(3)'});
  for (i = 0; i < selects.length; i ++) {
        selects[i].click()
    }
}
```

Comment: This should theoretically work, but it doesn't. I threw a console.log as an `else` statement, but that console.log is never run, so it seems like the conditions is returning true. Not sure hmm

Comment: @Dear1ofGdBear not sure about the `tagName`, changed it to `css`. If not work, you should investigate the html and find correct `css`. Also you can add `print` for debugging.